# No data was collected in my relation array in Laravel Eloquent method

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, eager-loading

I used eloquent method in my controller to collect data from my database, but something weird happened. If i use this code below,

```
$female_old_visitors = Treatment::with('diseases', 'patient', 'insurance', 'referer')
            ->leftJoin('patients', 'treatments.patient_id', 'patients.id')
            ->where('treatments.visit_status', 'old')
            ->where('patients.gender', 'female')
            ->whereBetween('treatments.date', $date_range)
            ->get();
```

i can get all the data that i want include diseases and referer

```
    Collection {#3053 ▼
  #items: array:25 [▼
    0 => Treatment {#2799 ▼
      ...
      #relations: array:4 [▼
        "diseases" => Collection {#3346 ▼
          #dates: array:1 [▶]
          #cascadeDeletes: array:1 [▶]
          #guarded: []
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "diseases"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:32 [▶]
          #original: array:32 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
          #forceDeleting: false
        }
        "patient" => Patient {#3328 ▶}
        "insurance" => Insurance {#3346 ▶}
        "referer" => TreatmentReferer {#3138 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
```

but when i use other code like this

```
$common_insurance_old_visitors = Treatment::with('diseases', 'patient', 'insurance', 'referer')
        ->leftJoin('insurances', 'treatments.insurance_id', 'insurances.id')
        ->where('treatments.visit_status', 'old')
        ->where('insurances.id', 1)
        ->whereBetween('treatments.date', $date_range)
        ->get();
```

all the data has been selected or collected except disease and referer

```
    Collection {#3053 ▼
  #items: array:25 [▼
    0 => Treatment {#2799 ▼
      ...
      #relations: array:4 [▼
        "diseases" => Collection {#3246 ▼
          #items: []
        }
        "patient" => Patient {#3328 ▶}
        "insurance" => Insurance {#3346 ▶}
        "referer" => null
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
```

i have been checking in my database, that the data is still there and the column is not empty, it should be collected just like the code i use first. Is it because i use left join uncorrectly? i am still new for laravel, thanks for anyone who giving me a solution for this problem

this is my model for Treatment

```
    <?php

namespace App;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    use Iatstuti\Database\Support\CascadeSoftDeletes;

class Treatment extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CascadeSoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $cascadeDeletes = ['medicines', 'actions', 'referer', 'diseases', 'queues'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function queues(){
        return $this->hasMany(TreatmentQueue::class);
    }

    public function treatmentType(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TreatmentType::class);
    }

    public function medicines(){
        return $this->hasMany(TreatmentMedicine::class)->with('medicine', 'recu');
    }

    public function actions(){
        return $this->hasMany(TreatmentAction::class)->with('action', 'doctor', 'nurse', 'recu', 'teeth', 'therapy', 'treatmentDisease');
    }

    public function insurance(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Insurance::class);
    }

    public function referer(){
        return $this->hasOne(TreatmentReferer::class)->with('puskesmas', 'disease');
    }

    public function diseases(){
        return $this->hasMany(TreatmentDisease::class)->with('disease', 'doctor', 'teeth');
    }

    public function patient(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`with()` is for **eager loading**. That basically means, along the main model, Laravel will preload the relationship(s) you specify. This is especially helpful if you have a collection of models and you want to load a relation for all of them. Because with eager loading you run only one additional DB query instead of one for every model in the collection.

### In your example.

you're using left join why? it already contain in `with()` you use `with('patient')` it means you join `treatments` to **left join** with `patient`

```
$female_old_visitors = Treatment::with('diseases', 'insurance', 'referer')
                        ->with(['patient' => function ($q) {
                                $q->where('gender', 'female');
                            }])
                            ->where('visit_status', 'old')
                            ->whereBetween('treatments.date', $date_range)
                            ->get();
```

[eager-loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: thanks,  it worked, but here is the problem, example all the records was 40, 30 male and 10 female, if i used my code for getting female, i can get 10 but with disease and referer relation problem, but if i used your code, the disease and referer problem were solved but i get 40 records instead 10